# Jordan form of matrix using the minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I've been studying Linear Algebra for the past few days and was busy with the topic of jordan matrices. I was making some exercices and came across the following one: Let $X^4 - 2X^3 + X^2$ be the minimal polynomial of some matrix A in $\mathbb{C}^{4x4}$, determine the jordan form of $A$ and $A^3$. I could determine the Jordan form of $A$ and got the following result
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Well I think this is it, I'm not sure tho. Following this I though the jordan form of $A^3$ would just be the one from $A$ but multiplied 3 times, however this didn't result in a jordan form at all and thus I got stuck. I thought that i could maybe determine the minimal polynomial of the matrix $A^3$ knowing the minimal polynomial of that from $A$, but haven't been able to progress with this problem. Does anyone have a tip? Any help would be greatly appreciated :))

Comment: your polynomial can be factored $$X^2(X-1)^2$$

Comment: Yes I used that fact to calculate the Jordan form for A, but I don't know how to determine the Jordan form of $A^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of a matrix $A$ and $A^3$ need not be same in general. For example, consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$ Then the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x^3.$ However, $A^3=0$ matrix and the minimal polynomial of $A^3$ is $x.$

Comment: Are the minimal polynomials of $A$ and $A^3$ somehow related?

Comment: @lukiluk Need not, if you are looking for a common factor in the minimal polynomial of a matrix $A$ and its cube.  For example, if $A=diag\{2,3,4\},$ then the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(x-2)(x-3)(x-4.)$ However, the minimal polynomial of $A^3$ is $(x-8)(x-27)(x-64).$ Although you can say that if $A$ is diagonalisable, then so is $A^3$ and hence the minimal polynomial of $A$ and $A^3$ will contain linear factors only.